# KML ARGB color doesn't shown correctly

Tags: google-maps-api-3, colors, kml

Here is the screenshot of the map that I'm working on:

[image]

and here is my KML code:

```
<Style id="line1">
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ff8C0A23</color>
        <width>2</width>
    </LineStyle>
</Style>

<Placemark>
<styleUrl>#line1</styleUrl>
<LineString><coordinates> ...
```

As you can see the color value is `ff8C0A23`, it's **ARGB**, right? So the **RGB** color is `8C0A23` that should looks like this:

[image]

But as you can see the color of the border is shown totally different in the map. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference

According to:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#color

The order of expression is aabbggrr

```
<color>
Color and opacity (alpha) values are expressed in hexadecimal notation. The range of values for any one color 
is 0 to 255 (00 to ff). For alpha, 00 is fully transparent and ff is fully opaque. The order of expression is 
aabbggrr, where aa=alpha (00 to ff); bb=blue (00 to ff); gg=green (00 to ff); rr=red (00 to ff). For example, 
if you want to apply a blue color with 50 percent opacity to an overlay, you would specify the following: 
<color>7fff0000</color>, where alpha=0x7f, blue=0xff, green=0x00, and red=0x00.
```

See this color chooser:
http://www.zonums.com/gmaps/kml_color/

Comment: Oh, so this is ABGR not ARGB? thanks, let me see if it's working or not ... :)

Comment: I changed that to `ff230a8c` and it's working now! Thanks man! :)